# Sharepoint Rest Api Search query, getting a field with rich text

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I am trying to get a field with a rich text but it is striping all the html in the search query. Is there a way to get the html rather than the rich text?

`https://{domain}.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27claim%27&selectproperties=%27Title,Question,Answer%27`

`<d:Key>Answer</d:Key>
<d:Value xml:space="preserve"> See THIS Form​ . ​ </d:Value>`

Answer is the Rich text field with a link in it, When I do a GET (`_api/web/lists/getbytitle`), it comes back with a link in that field.

Basically, I want to avoid having to call search then call a GET to replace the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by looking through the search properties and using the ID in the path to use a GET List 
`_api/web/lists/getbytitle('title')/items('1')`

then replacing the column in search with the rich text with the one from the GET.

I only need 3 results or so, so this was not a problem for me.

It looks like in the search query, doesnt give back any html tags for the rich text column.